# correct or efficient way of accessing DOM object in aspx pages

Tags: javascript, aspx

I want to get the value of textbox that a user enters. Below is the code snippet of aspx page :

```
<asp:TextBox id="txtUserName" runat="server" />
```

Now which is the best way to access DOM object in aspx page

1.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var value= document.getElementById(<%= txtUserName.ClientID %>).value;
alert(value);
</script>
```

2.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var value= document.getElementById("txtUserName").value;
alert(value);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### SharePoint 2013/SharePoint Online

In .NET Framework 4 was introduced [ClientIDMode property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.web.ui.clientidmode(v=vs.100).aspx) that specifies how ASP.NET generates the `ClientID` for a control that can be accessed in client script.

To summarize, since SharePoint 2013 targets .NET Framework 4, `ClientIDMode` could be utilized  that simplifies the access of control in the client side as demonstrated below:

Example:

```
<asp:TextBox id="boxUserName" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

JavaScript:

```
var boxUserName = document.getElementById("boxUserName")
```

### SharePoint 2010 and earlier versions

> Prerequisites: [jQuery library](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) is used that offers a powerful set
>   of tools for matching a set of elements in a document.

**Option 1**

Use selector to find element by Id, for example:

```
var quickLaunch = $('[id$=V4QuickLaunchMenu]'); // find element with id which ends with the text 'V4QuickLaunchMenu'
```

**Option 2**

Use `CssClass` to specify element class, for example:

```
<asp:TextBox id="boxUserName" runat="server" CssClass="text-box" />
```

and then use class selector:

```
var boxUserName = $('input.text-box');
```

### References

- [How to: Access Controls from JavaScript by ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd410598(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: so this means if an asp element doesn't specified clientIdMode then using getElementById might fails or can generate null exception

Comment: One correction for your comment, when ClientIDMode="Static" is specified, then the element id is not changed

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 is the correct way to do but just change the variable name to something different  as it is JavaScript keyword

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var _value= document.getElementById(<%= txtUserName.ClientID %>).value;
 alert(value);
</script>
```

But I prefer to use jQuery which make life much easier. For that add jQuery file in your aspx or masterpage. Then use below line

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){     
   var _value= $(<%= txtUserName.ClientID %>).val();
   alert(value);
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Thnaks but I'm facing a problem which is when I put the javascript in JS file[JS code is taken out from aspx file] I am getting null exception on accessing these element. Also can u please tell me the difference between them

Comment: Can you explain it bit more. How you are adding code and referencing to the page.

Comment: I have taken out the code from <script> tag and place it into a JS file. Now its throwing the null exception for (<%= txtUserName.ClientID %>).val() when I am trying to read value but document.getElementById("txtUserName").value; is working fine

Comment: It is correct, it will throw null as <%= %> is server side tag and it will not execute from js file as it is client side file. Next thing if you are setting ClientIDMode="Static"  than it will not change id of the element, then you don't need to use server tag. Hope you got my point.